# Read-only primitive collection in Entity Framework Core 8

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I want to use the new [primitive collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#primitive-collections) feature, but at the same time I want to properly encapsulate changes to my collection.

I have an entity like this:

```
public class User
{
    private readonly List<string> _roles = new();

    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Roles => _roles;
}
```

When I try to configure `Roles` using `.PrimitiveCollection()`, I get an error

> The type 'IReadOnlyCollection' cannot be used as a primitive collection because it is read-only. Read-only collections of primitive types are not supported.

If I instead configure the field `_roles` as the primitive collection and ignore `Roles`, it works, but then I cannot query against `Roles`.

Does anyone know of a solution for this problem?

Entity type configurations with `Roles` as primitive collection for completeness:

```
public class UserEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.PrimitiveCollection(x => x.Roles);
    }
}
```

With `_roles` as primitive collection:

```
public class UserEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.Ignore(x => x.Roles);
        builder.PrimitiveCollection<List<string>>("_roles")
               .HasColumnName(nameof(User.Roles));
    }
}
```

Comment: Types used with entity framework needs to follow the rules for EF. This often means compromising on things like encapsulation. If this is a problem you can always separate the types used in EF from the types in the rest of your application. i.e. with wrappers/adapters/converters.

Comment: The best you can get is to make the setter private (`List<string> Roles { get; private set; }`). Which of course doesn't help much.

Comment: No luck - [Support read-only collections of primitive types #31722](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31722). From what I see, the minimum required currently is `IList<T>` or derived. Even `ICollection<T>` is not working, `IEnumerable<T>` is accepted, but runtime exception when reading from database.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, don't know why I couldn't find that issue. Will just have to wait then.